# podman: OCI Runtime crun is in use by a container, but is not available (not in configuration file or not installed)

Tags: container, podman

I'm not sure why I am getting this error:

```
$ podman ps -a
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE                           COMMAND           CREATED       STATUS           PORTS                 NAMES
b18ec89fc0ec  docker.io/library/httpd:latest  httpd-foreground  11 hours ago  Up 11 hours ago  0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp  relaxed_noether

$ sudo podman container checkpoint b18ec89fc0ec
[sudo] password for user: 
ERRO[0000] OCI Runtime crun is in use by a container, but is not available (not in configuration file or not installed) 
ERRO[0000] Refreshing container 3d8463b462585d851c706494eff834b843b327554f9e32020427be36ee864235: failed to get attach socket path for container 3d8463b462585d851c706494eff834b843b327554f9e32020427be36ee864235: runtime crun is missing: OCI runtime attempted to invoke a command that was not found 
Error: no container with name or ID "b18ec89fc0ec" found: no such container

$ podman ps -a
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE                           COMMAND           CREATED       STATUS           PORTS                 NAMES
b18ec89fc0ec  docker.io/library/httpd:latest  httpd-foreground  11 hours ago  Up 11 hours ago  0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp  relaxed_noether
```

Ubuntu 22.04

Originally installed podman 3.4.4 via

```
sudo apt install podman
```

Couldn't get checkpoint save and restore working on that version.

Built podman 4.2.0-dev from source.
Getting this crun error.

Searched around but was not able to find other instances of this error.

My guess is that
1: podman 3.3.4 for Ubuntu 22.04 was configured to use crun
2: I built podman 4.2.0-dev to use runc
3: *something* from the first install did not get deleted and is messing with my 2nd install

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me recently so what I found was I had an old container in a stopped state using crun.

> podman ps -a

showed an old container and all I had to do was rm it and the error was gone.